# Can I rotate the Miller indices?

Tags: symmetry, crystals

I was just wondering if I could rotate the axes of miller indices. Like $x$ goes where $y$ is and $y$ goes where $z$ is and $z$ goes where $x$ is. As long as I satisfy the logic of the concept. I should be fine right?

[image]
[image]

Both of these should be equivalent right?